# User, Order, Meal, Item and their ActiveRecord associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to figure out what the appropriate ActiveRecord associations would be for my models. I am building a meal customization and ordering system for a website where **Users** can select from a number of **Items** and build a **Meal** and repeat this multiple times for a single **Order**.

My current setup is as follow:

**User**

```
has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :meals, through: :orders
```

**Order**

```
belongs_to :user
has_and_belongs_to_many :meals
```

**Meal**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
has_and_belongs_to_many :items
```

**Item**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :meals
```

I suppose my question then would come in two parts:

1) does my current setup allow for multiple items to be assigned to a single meal, and possibly to other meals for a single order.

2) will I be able to access a user's previous meals to provide a shortcut when making new orders.

thanks a bunch in advance from a first time question asker!

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, yes, you have set up a many-to-many relationship between your meals and items (assuming you have the correctly named database columns as well).

To your second question, you may have to wright a custom query for it as I'm not sure if active record is setup to do the multi layer query you're asking it to do (i.e. get all the meals from all the orders for a given user). Something like

`past_meals = Set.new`

`users.orders.each {|o| past_meals += o.meals}` would certainly work but could be made much more efficient if you needed it to.

However, even though `has_many_and_belongs_to` does work for what you're doing, using it isn't recommended. The community is much more in favor of making a join table doing a has_many_through relationship with that.

You in no means have to do that but most people would suggest it and it could save you some work down the road.